# How to create pop up app menus

Tags: ios

I have been looking at an application called Houzz and like the way it works, It has a (sorry for the bad phrasing) pop up tab menu on the left hand side of the tab bar, similar to the vidiprinter in the Sky Sports app and also has a selection of tags in the images that link to more details, that respond to the orientation of the phone.

I would like to know how to create these features and am wondering if anyone is familiar with these applications or features and knows how they are done to point me in the right direction.

Comment: This question is rather useless, as apps can change over time. Better provide screenshots and more importantly: describe what you have tried to solve this and even better: ask/search for specific questions! Not tutorials in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Apple library:

[SplitViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html)

And furthermore take a look at Ray Wenderlichs Tutorial:

[UISplitViewController](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29469/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-in-ios-6-uisplitview-tutorial)

I think this should be a good way for you to learn this.

Regards,

Noah